# if statement variable starts with

Tags: php

Is there a way of asking if a variable starts with...

The problem i have is in a database i have both image files and audio files i would like an if statement that said if $file starts with "audio/......."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (strpos($file,'audio/') === 0 ) 
{
  echo "audio/ found at start";
}
```

Comment: `strpos()` returns `false`, if `$needle` is not found in the string. You must use `===`, because `(false == 0) === true`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get a part of a string, and then you can check if it is equal to `'audio/'`.

```
if (substr($file, 0, 6)=='audio/') {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such builtin function, but you can use string comparison for equivalent behaviour

```
if (strncmp('audio/', $file, 6) === 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Or a more common, but less performant solution

```
if (substr($file, 0, 6) === 'audio/') {
  // do something
}
```

However, you should be able to select the corresponding rows right from the database

```
WHERE column LIKE 'audio/%'
```

Comment: +1 for the `strncmp` solution, it seems to be cleaner. I would not say it is that much more performant, we are talking about 6 characters :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Its more performant in the way the interpreter handles it, not on how fast one can type it ;) Some say, its about 20% faster than the `substr()`-solution. I didnt test it myself and of course we are talking about very small durations. However, I think its at least good to know :)

Comment: I wasn't talking about typing speed either :). I just said that when you have to get 6 chars from a short string, it does not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( substr($file,0,strlen($start))===$start ) ...
```

or

```
if ( substr_compare($file,$start,0,strlen($start),true)==0 ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use substr like

```
if (substr($file,0,5) == "audio")
```

etc

Comment: He is trying to get files that are in the `audio` directory. This will get also simple files without a dir if their filename starts with 'audio' (ex. audio1.wav) and files in dirs with a name starting with 'audio' (ex. audiofos/x.jpg).